# How to get error sql from PostgresException

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, npgsql, .net-6.0

ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application uses EF Core and Npgsql.

Ef Core command like

```
await ctx.Kasutajas.Where((k) => k.Kasutaja1 == suurusername).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

throws PostgresException in case of missing column. BatchCommand  property in null. It looks like EF Core does not use batch command interface. How to get error sql in this case?

```
   app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await next.Invoke();
                }
                catch (PostgresException ex)
                {
ex.BatchCommand in null.
ex.InternalQuery is null.
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.InternalQuery);
?? How to get error Sql ?
                }
                }
            });
```

In .NET 5 Ngpsql had statement property for this but it was removed according to

https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/6.0.html#npgsqlstatement-and-postgresexceptionstatement-have-been-removed

How to get error SQL in CATCH block in exception handler?
Discussion in https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/4222
does not provide solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgresException.BatchCommand support is being added for regular commands, like the PostgresException.Statement in pre-6.0 Npgsql. See https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/4222.